# Manually resetting jquery stars plugin after ajax form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently using the [jQuery Stars plugin](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/) on my rails application. I am using ajax to submit a form that includes these stars so after a successful submit the page does not reload and the stars do not reset. How can I clear these persistent stars so the form is completely reset and ready for the next submit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out all you need to do is this

```
$('input.star').rating('select', false)
```

Using Kishore's method, stars will display again if you hover over them.

Comment: I am trying this with Jquery Mobile and it says: TypeError: $(...).rating is not a function

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is no direct way to clear stars

look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BxTvW/) if you click on clear starts all the stars are cleared.

so in your case if the form is submitted successfully in the success function add this code

```
$('.ratings').find('input[type=radio]').attr("checked", false);
$('.star-rating-control').find('.star-rating-live').removeClass('star-rating-on');
```

You might have to replace `ratings` class with the appropriate one that you are using.